# How to flush a SocketChannel in Java NIO?

Tags: java, nio

In Java IO, an `OutputStream` can use `flush()` method to make sure data is sent at once.

Is there a corresponding function in Java NIO for [`SocketChannel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html)? As far as I know, there is a `force()` method for `FileChannel` to flush data.

Might be a very naive question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either `.force()` or `.getFD.sync()`

Update: Since you updated your question to be more specific on a SocketChannel (it was generally NIO), please see my reply instead.

Comment: Yep. But that is for FileChannel, right? I need the same function for SocketChannel.

Comment: A SocketChannel cant't be flushed. You'll have to check wheter the data is sent completely instead.

Comment: Thanks. This is also help :). BTW, would u please recommend some links or book to getting to know Java NIO. Thanks Again!

Comment: I mainly use Java API docs - http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/overview-summary.html

Comment: Please see your reply instead? This *is* your reply. It's also wrong.

Comment: Note for past me: it looks like HTTP signals the reader is done by having the client close the client->server stream once the client has received all the data it's expecting.

Comment: And "you'll have to check whether the data is sent completely instead": how? Java provides no API for that. But as a `SocketChannel` doesn't *need* to be flushed, it's all moot anyway. Answer is completely incorrect.

Comment: @Erhannis HTTP has nothing to do with it: not that your description is correct anyway.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky There is nothing here that justifies your editing an incorrect answer into a correct answer. Edit reverted.

Comment: @user207421 Wait, what? You edited a correct answer into an incorrect one? O_o  You think I did it for points or "rules"? I did it to help users. Who is your edit supposed to help? Did you do it just so that your answer would get more rep? Are you thinking straight?

Answer (score 12):

`OutputStream.flush()` does nothing except flush the buffers of any `BufferedOutputStream`s or `ObjectOutputStream`s or `PrintStream`s that are in the stack.

Specifically, it doesn't do anything corresponding to `FileChannel.force()` or `getFD().sync()`. It just flushes stream buffers from the JVM into (in this case) the socket send buffer in the kernel.

`SocketChannel.write()` doesn't involve any such buffering at all: it goes directly to the socket send buffer in the kernel. So there is nothing to flush, so there is no flush operation.

Comment: Thanks! Learned more about NIO :-)

Comment: It looks like there IS a buffer somewhere (maybe the mentioned "socket send buffer") - if you close the stream too soon after writing data, it doesn't get sent.  But I don't know of a way to wait until the buffer is empty.  Looks like for HTTP connections, the client closes the client->server stream once the client has received all the data it's expecting, so if you have the server read from the client until the stream closes, you can use that as a signal that the data made it.

Comment: @Erhannis "If you close the stream too soon after writing data, it doesn't get sent": that would be a violation of the TCP protocol. Never seen it myself in 20 years of NIO. You must have some programming error somewhere.

Comment: @user207421 Huh, well, I can't replicate it at the moment, so you may well be right.  I vaguely remember that if I added a sleep before the close, then the problem went away, so I'm not completely convinced, but I'll cautiously proceed on the assumption you're right.

Answer (score 4):

When you force() the data to disk, the OS can determine it has been written to disk successfully.  However TCP communication is more complex and the data passes through many stages outside the OSes control. Generally speaking, the OS wills end out the data as soon as possible and won't buffer the socket data (typically about 64 KB) to the degree it will buffer disk writes (sometimes GBs)

The best way to ensure the data has been received successfully is to have the other end send a response.

If you want data to be sent as fast as possible you can try turning nagle off, however most OSes are pretty smart at optimising this and turning it off doesn't make as much difference as it used.

Comment: A thing I've just discovered: `socketChannel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_LINGER, N)` tells the system to wait up to N seconds before closing the channel if unsent data is present.

Comment: @Erhannis SO_LINGER has no effect on whether the pending data is sent - it is: it only affects whether `close()` blocks while that is happening.